# HTML form message with php/jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

So let's say I have a form with 3 fields. Name, email and message. When I hit the submit button I'd like to have it checked if the email has the @xxxx.com layout and if a name and message are given. There should be an error message fading in or a success message fading in after it gets checked without reloading the page. How exactly can I do this with php and jquery and where can I find good practice around this specific type of situation?

Comment: Seriously ... this topic has been discussed many times on SO. At least, bring some source code and let us help you then.

Comment: The easiest way is using HTML5's new features: Set the input field type to "email" and it should warn if the entered string is not an email adress. For anything more complex than that, read the other comments about the jQuery validation plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using the jQuery plugin: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation. In fact, the minimal setup requires only one line of javascript, `$("#commentForm").validate();`. However, remember to check the data on the server-side using php, in case the user has disabled javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery validate plugin http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation
For the server side, you still need to validate it, in a case that javascript it's disable and for checking integrity issues with your data

Answer (score 0):

My two favorite inline validators are:

**Ketchup**
http://demos.usejquery.com/ketchup-plugin/

and

**Inline Validation**
http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/

Both are super simple to apply (in the case of the inline validator, just add a class declaration) and work very well.

I can't emphasize enough, though, that you still need to check on the PHP end with regex/length/isset type validation.